# How do apt or dnf package managers replace critical files?

Tags: apt, package-managers, package-management, dnf

I was trying to copy some libraries into my shared library path and I accidentally replaced libc.so with a newer version by `cp` command and the whole system froze. restarted it and it was fine again. There are too many programs in Linux that use libc.so, and apparently replacing it (even with a newer version) could cause a stroke to the system.

So how do package managers like apt or dnf update/replace critical files like libc which many program depend on?